Visualizing the elements of a finite group as a closed parametric curve?
Let $G$ be a finite group with $n = |G|$ elements. By Cayley's theorem for finite groups, we have an injective homomorphism of groups:
$$
    \pi : G  \rightarrow S_n, \quad g \mapsto \pi(g)
$$
where each group element $g$ is mapped to the permutation of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $n=|G|$ elements, which it generates by left multiplication:
$$
\pi(g): G \rightarrow G, \quad x \mapsto g \cdot x
$$
We want to associate to each group element $g$ a matrix and then use the Frobenius inner product to define a positive semi-definite function $k$ on the group $G$ as follows:
It is known, see for instance "The Kendall and Mallows Kernels for Permutations" by Yunlong Jiao and Jean-Philippe Vert, that the Kendall-tau function can be made into a positive semi-definite kernel $k$ for permutations.
Let $\mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}$ be the indicator function, which is $=1$ if the boolean variable $x$ is true and $0$ if the boolean variable $x$ is false, and let:
$$
    \phi: S_n \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R}), \quad \sigma \mapsto \left(\mathbf{1}_{\{\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)\}}-\mathbf{1}_{\{\sigma(i)<\sigma(j)\}}\right)_{1\le i,j \le n}
$$
where $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ denotes $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$.
The embedding from the finite group $G$ to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is then given by:
$$
    \psi: G \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R}), \quad g \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}} \cdot \phi(\pi(g))
$$
We use the Frobenius inner product on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, which is given by:
$$
   \left \langle A, B \right \rangle := \operatorname{tr}(A \cdot B^T) 
$$
to define a positive semi-definite, symmetric function $k$ on $G$:
$$
   k: G \times G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad (g,h) \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(\psi(g) \cdot \psi(h)^T) 
$$
Examples
The Klein-Four group
Let $G$ be the Klein-Four group. The following SageMath code computes some of the constructions above:
import numpy as np
import itertools
from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import rbf_kernel

def regularPermutationsInSymmetricGroup(finiteGroup):
    from sage.matrix.operation_table import OperationTable
    G = finiteGroup
    O = OperationTable(G, operator.mul, names="elements")
    print(latex(O.table()))
    ll = [ Permutation([xx + 1 for xx in x]) for x in O.table()] 
    return ll

def embeddInMatrixSpace(sigma):
    """sigma = Permutation"""
    n = len(sigma)
    m = matrix([[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)])
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            m[i,j] = 1*(sigma(i+1) > sigma(j+1)) - 1*(sigma(i+1) < sigma(j+1))
    return m

def kk(p1, p2):
    m1 = embeddInMatrixSpace(p1)
    m2 = embeddInMatrixSpace(p2)
    return (m1 * m2.transpose()).trace()

def grammat(group):
    perms = regularPermutationsInSymmetricGroup(group)    
    return matrix([[kk(p1,p2) for p1 in perms] for p2 in perms])

The Cayley table is given by:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\
\hline
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
For $[1, 2, 3, 4]$, we get the following matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
For $[2, 1, 4, 3]$, we get the following matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Similarly:
$[3, 4, 1, 2]$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$[4, 3, 2, 1]$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Here is the (normalized) Gram matrix of $k$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & -1 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 1 & -1 & -\frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{3} & -1 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} \\
-1 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We notice that all matrices in these examples have the following form:

All entries are $0$, $-1$, or $+1$.
The diagonal entries are all $0$.
Off-diagonal entries are only $+1$ or $-1$.
$M = -M^{\mathrm{T}}$ (the matrix is skew-symmetric).

The cyclic group $C_4$
Similarly, for $C_4$, we calculate:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
\hline
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
$[1, 2, 3, 4]$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$[2, 3, 4, 1]$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$[3, 4, 1, 2]$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$[4, 1, 2, 3]$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Here is the (normalized) Gram matrix of $k$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Questions

Is $k(xg,xh) = k(gx,hx) = k(g,h) \text{ for all } x,g,h \in G$?
Is $\phi$ an injective mapping?
Let $\chi_t(g) =$ the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $\phi(g)$ in variable $t$. Is $\chi_t(g) = \chi_t(h)$ for all $g,h \in G$?
What properties does $\psi(g)$ inherit from properties of skew-symmetric matrices?
Is $\det(\phi(\pi(g))) = 1$ if $n \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and $0$ otherwise?
What properties can be deduced from the Pfaffian of $\phi(\pi(g))$?
The eigenvalues of $\phi(\pi(g))$ are, since the matrix is skew-symmetric, either $=0$ in the $n =$ odd case and the others come in pairs of purely imaginary eigenvalues, or are all purely imaginary: $\lambda i, -\lambda i$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$?

The method to generate a closed parametric curve for $g \in G$ is given by:
$$f_g(t):= \sum_{m=1 }^n  m\exp(k(g,h_m) \cdot t \cdot i)$$
where $h_1, h_2, \cdots, h_n$ are all elements of $G$ in some order.
Here are some images generated with this method:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4CV4kZ2Nbs

Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477754/visualizing-the-elements-of-a-finite-group-and-does-the-gram-matrix-determine-th without notification to either site, in violation of site rules.

@GerryMyerson: The questions are related, similar, and have the same motivation, but they are not equal. Besides, I simply forgot to mention that I had posted it on MSE or MO. Thanks for the reminder!

Link to a poster with 30 groups visualized (97MB, png): http://www.orges-leka.de/visualization_of_finite_groups.png

We provide the affirmative answers of (2), (3), (5), and (7), the partially affirmative and partially negative answer of (1), and the trivial answers of (4) and (6).
Let $n$ be any natural number and $\sigma\in S_n$ be any permutation. It is easy to see that the matrix $\phi(\sigma)$ is skew-symmetric, so it inherits all properties common to skew-symmetric matrices, that provides the trivial answer of (4).
To provide an affirmative answer of (2) note that for each natural $i\le n$, we have $\sigma(i)$ is equal to $$|\{j\in\{1,\dots,n\}:\sigma(j)<\sigma(i)\}|+1$$ that is to the number of ones in the $i$th row of $\phi(\sigma)$ plus $1$.
Now we recall the usual matrix representation $r:S_n\to M_n(\mathbb R)$. Namely, for each natural $i,j\le n$ let the $(i,j)$th entry of the matrix $r(\sigma)$ is $1$, if $\sigma(i)=j$, and $0$, otherwise. It is easy to check that $r$ is a homomorphism.
It is easy to check that $\phi(\sigma)=r(\sigma)^{-1}\phi(1)r(\sigma)$.
This provides the affirmative answer of (3). Moreover, $r(\sigma)^{-1}=r(\sigma)^T$ and the definition of the determinant implies that $\det r(\sigma)$ equals $1$, when the permutation $\sigma$ is even, and equals $-1$, otherwise. Therefore, when the Pfaffian $\operatorname{Pf} \phi(\sigma)$ of $\phi(\sigma)$ exists (that is when $n$ is even), we have $\phi(\sigma)=\det r(\sigma)\cdot \operatorname{Pf}\phi(1)$,
that is $\operatorname{Pf} \phi(\sigma)$ equals $\operatorname{Pf}\phi(1)$, when the permutation $\sigma$ is even, and equals $-\operatorname{Pf}\phi(1)$, otherwise. This provides the trivial answer of (6).
Let $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix, and $t$ be any real number. Then $$\det(\phi(\sigma)- tI)=\det (r(\sigma)^{-1}\phi(1)r(\sigma)-tI)=\det (\phi(1)-tI)=$$
$$\frac 12\left((-t+1)^n+(-t-1)^n\right).$$
The last inequality is according to Problem 392 from [Pro].
In particular, $\det \phi(\sigma)=\frac 12\left(1+(-1)^n\right)$, which answers (5) affirmatively.
The eigenvalues of $\phi(\sigma)$ have the form $\frac {1+\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}$, where $\varepsilon$ is any of $n$ $n$th roots of $-1$. That is $\varepsilon=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$, where $\alpha=\frac{(1+2k)\pi}{n}$, $k\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$. Then
$$\frac {1+\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}=\frac {1+\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha}{1-\cos\alpha-i\sin\alpha}=
\frac {(1+\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)(1-\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)}{(1-\cos\alpha-i\sin\alpha)(1-\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)}=
$$
$$
\frac {(1+i\sin\alpha)^2-\cos^2\alpha}{(1-\cos\alpha)^2+\sin^2\alpha}=
\frac {2i\sin\alpha}{2-2\cos\alpha}=i\operatorname{ctan}\frac{\alpha}2,$$
which answers (7) affirmatively.
Finally, consider (1). Let $g$ and $h$ be any elements of the group $G$. Then
$$k(g,h)=\operatorname{tr}\left(\psi(g) \cdot \psi(h)^T\right)=$$
$$\frac 1{n(n-1)}\operatorname{tr}\left(\phi(\pi(g)) \cdot \phi(\pi(h))^T\right) =$$
$$\frac 1{n(n-1)}\operatorname{tr}\left(r(\pi(g))^{-1}\phi(1)r(\pi(g)) \cdot (r(\pi(h))^{-1}\phi(1)r(\pi(h)))^T\right)=$$
$$\frac 1{n(n-1)}\operatorname{tr}\left(r(\pi(g))^{-1}\phi(1)r(\pi(g)) \cdot r(\pi(h))^T \phi(1)^T (r(\pi(h))^{-1})^T\right)=$$
$$\frac 1{n(n-1)}\operatorname{tr}\left(r(\pi(g))^{-1}\phi(1)r(\pi(g)) \cdot r(\pi(h))^{-1} \phi(1)^T r(\pi(h))\right)=$$
$$\frac 1{n(n-1)}\operatorname{tr}\left(r(\pi(g))^{-1}\phi(1)r(\pi(gh^{-1}))\phi(1)^T r(\pi(h))\right)=$$
$$\frac 1{n(n-1)}\operatorname{tr}\left(\phi(1)r(\pi(gh^{-1}))\phi(1)^T r(\pi(h))r(\pi(g))^{-1}\right)=$$
$$\frac 1{n(n-1)}\operatorname{tr}\left(\phi(1)r(\pi(gh^{-1}))\phi(1)^T r(\pi(hg^{-1}))\right).$$
Therefore $k(gx,hx)=k(g,h)$ for each $x\in G$.
If, moreover $k(xg,xh)=k(g,h)$ for each $x\in G$ then $k(1,x^{-1}gx)=k(1,g)$ for each $g,x\in G$.
But the latter condition can be violated. Indeed, let $G=S_3$. It is well-known that the permutations $(12)$, $(13)$, and $(23)$ from $G$ are pairwise conjugated. So if (1) holds then $k(1,(12))=k(1,(13))=k(1,(23))$, that is the Gram-matrix for $S_3$ (from your question at MathOverflow) has a row with three equal entries, a contradiction.
References
[Pro] Proskuryakov I.V., A collection of linear algebra problems, in Russian (Проскуряков И.В. Сборник задач по линейной алгебре).

Thanks for your answer. I had similar ideas but not written down so to say. I would also be interested in the first question and maybe if one can prove that the Gram matrix already determines the group, but this is maybe another topic?

@mathoverflowUser Thanks for your kind words. I am still updating the answer. The first question leads to technical calculations, but I shall try to deal it. Also I am going to look at your question from MO about the Gram-Matrix.

Thanks for your work. I edited the MO question to reflect what I mean with Gram matrix.

Thank you very much for this detailed answer!

@mathoverflowUser I completed my answer, see its end.
